# Appengine Java & GWT - Cannot recreate and open a channel

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, channel-api

I'm using App engine Channel API with gwt-gae-channel library (v. 0.4) in GWT and i'm trying to test the recreation of a channel, after expiration (i.e. onError is called with code 401).

The test is:

- use GWT RPC method to create a channel (clientID= and expiration = 1 minute) and get the token needed: createTestChannel(useremail).

- call ChannelFactory.createChannel(token, new ChannelCreatedCallback() { ... }) and channel.open(new MySocketListener(){...})

- when onError(...) is called (channel expires) I try to call createTestChannel(useremail) again (to get a new token for the same clientID) and open a channel, but I always get onError() and onClose() called .

If I refresh the page or open a new tab with the same code, the first channel creation works ok, but after each channel expiration, I cannot recreate them. I also tried another clientID, but it wont work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!searchin/google-appengine-java/channel/google-appengine-java/kD3H6BWNYuA/NivXiDrqW7QJ

Comment: I only tested this localhost, maybe I should try to test this on production server also...

Answer (score 0):

You must create a new channel on the server and get the new token. From the docs :

Tokens expire in two hours. If a client remains connected to a channel for longer than two hours, the socket’s onerror() and onclose() callbacks are called. At this point the client can make an XHR request to the application to request a new token.

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/channel/overview.html#Tokens_and_Security

Comment: When the channel is closed I call the same rpc method createTestChannel(username), witch creates a channel and returns a token. But after I receive the new token I get onError() and onClose() called when I try to open the channel (and no exception on the server side is thrown).

Comment: Weird. I have to rest my case.

Comment: I have the same problem. Also with the gwt-gae-channel library. I recreate the token and get onError() and onClose() callbacks.